# ¿Se pueden agrupar los elementos de la leyenda en kendoChart con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendoui, telerik

Saludos, necesitaría agrupar los elementos de las series de un Kendochart, de forma que queden separados del siguiente modo:

**Título del grupo 1**:

Serie 1.

Serie 2.

**Título del grupo 2**:

Serie 3.

Serie 4.

He intentado hacerlo con un template en el label del siguiente modo:

```
 legend: {
                labels: {
                    template: kendo.template($("legend-template").html())
                }
            },
```

Y en el Template, para luego acceder a través del ID:

<script id="legend-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div id="Leyenda">  #: text # </div>
</script>
</code>

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESUELTO** La solución ha sido crear un div con un checkbox para cada una de las Series, de modo que desde Jquery alternas la propiedad visible de cada una de las series en el chart.

Por ejemplo sería:

```
$("#SerieName").change(function () {
            if ($("#SerieName").is(":checked")) {
                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").options.series[0].visible = true;
                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();

            } else {

                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").options.series[0].visible = false;
                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
            }
        });
```